# Redis NOAUTH Authentication required. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379] Laravel

Tags: api, laravel, redis, dingo-api

I am working on a Laravel project that uses dingo package to manage some APIs. I changed `CACHE_DRIVER=array` variable in my `.env` file to `CACHE_DRIVER=redis` because dingo no longer support `array` for `CACHE_DRIVER`. I therefore installed redis on my system and included the package in my Laravel project by adding `"predis/predis": "~1.0"` in my `composer.json` and updating with the command `composer update`. Up until now everything works just fine. However, to create database table and seed them using `php artisan migrate --seed`, I get the error:

> [Predis\Connection\ConnectionException]
>     `SELECT` failed: NOAUTH Authentication required. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Note: when I was installing redis, I added a password. I also authenticated using the two commands `redis-cli` to switch to redis and then `AUTH mypassword`. Yet when I try to seed, it still throws the same error. Please what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check configuration, if you may have master password in it.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with setting redis password in `REDIS_PASSWORD` environment variable (e.g. in `.env` file). See https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/redis#configuration for more details about redis configuration in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your redis server when you are seeding.

Run: `redis-server`